# .htaccess redirect not working. redirect keeps looping

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I wish to redirect '/portfolio' to '/portfolio/architectural-photography' however the htaccess redirection is not working. I get a 'this page isn't redirecting properly' error page.

It seems to loop the end bit continually and is trying to go to - http://www.danielbinks.co.uk/portfolio/architectural-photography/architectural-photography/architectural-photography/architectural-photography/architectural-photography/architectural-photography/architectural-photography

Here's my rule (please tell me what's wrong):

```
redirect 301 /portfolio http://www.danielbinks.co.uk/portfolio/architectural-photography
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Redirect` directive links two path nodes together, since the target of your redirect matches the source, it'll just keep looping. Try using `RedirectMatch` instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/portfolio/?$ http://www.danielbinks.co.uk/portfolio/architectural-photography
```